# Pass List from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i am trying to pass List from view to controller but i am getting null value. code is written as follows :

model class :

```
public class testModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<myModel> ParameterList {get;set;}
}
```

jquery and ajax code to post data to controller :

```
var myModel = {
                  "Name":"test",      
                  "Description":"desc"      
                };

        var Object = {
            Name: $("#Name").val(),
            ParameterList : myModel
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/controller/action',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(Object),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {   }
                else { }
            }
        });
```

i am getting value for Name property but not for ParameterList. 
What is wrong here ? am i missing anything ?

Please help me out.

Thanks

Edit : Controller Code from comments,

```
 public JsonResult Save(Object Obj) 
 {
 // logic for managing model and db save
 }
```

Comment: post the code for your controller as well

Comment: public JsonResult Save(Object Obj) { // logic for managing model and db save}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337784/how-to-pass-the-list-of-objects-from-view-to-mvc-controller-using-json-stringify

Answer (score 3):

You said,

> I am getting value for Name property but not for ParameterList.

Which makes me wonder what is the structure of `myModel`, as you have declared ParameterList as a list of myModel type : `List<myModel> ParameterList`

Also I would recommend you to log `JSON.stringify(Object)` to console and check the Json value you are actually posting to the controller.

Here is what I found you must be posting back

```
{"Name":"yasser","ParameterList":{"Name":"test","Description":"desc"}}
```

Also read these articles :

[How can I pass complex json object view to controller in ASP.net MVC](http://forums.asp.net/t/1694922.aspx/1)

[Pass JSON object from Javascript code to MVC controller](http://krishnarajb.wordpress.com/2009/05/28/pass-json-object-from-javascript-code-to-mvc-controller/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myModel = [{
              "Name":"test",      
              "Description":"desc"      
            }];

    var Object = {
        Name: $("#Name").val(),
        ParameterList : myModel
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/controller/action',
        type: 'POST',
        data: Object,
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {   }
            else { }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this..Hope this would help!!

script:

```
var emp = [{ 'empid': 1, 'name': 'sasi' },{ 'empid': 2, 'name': 'sathish'}];
emp = JSON.stringify(emp)
$.post("/Home/getemplist/", { 'emp': emp })
```

Controller:

Here i just changed the parameter to string type. using JavaScriptSerializer you can able to convert this string data to your class list objects.. you can understand it better if u see my code below:

```
public void getemplist(string emp) 
{
    List<Emp> personData;
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    personData = jss.Deserialize<List<Emp>>(emp);
    // DO YOUR OPERATION ON LIST OBJECT

}
```